# Why does passing a state value pass a dictionary?

Tags: reactjs

I'm passing a state value to a component.

```js
function MySubComponent(count) {
  console.log(count);
  return null;
}

export function MyComponent() {
  let [state, setState] = useState({count: 1});
  return <MySubComponent state={state.count} />;
}
```

I expect it to log `1`, but instead it logs `{state: 1}`. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"count" in your subComponent is treating as props.
If you expecting the log output is "1", then you can change it into:

```
function MySubComponent({state}) {
  console.log(state);
  return null;
}
```

OR:

```
function MySubComponent(props) {
      console.log(props.state);
      return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In **MyComponent.js**,

In this line,

```
<MySubComponent state={state.count} />;
```

You are mentioning the props name as `state` which you could change it to `count` so that you can access the count value in `MySubComponent` .

So it would be like,

```
<MySubComponent count={state.count} />
```

In **MySubComponent.js** , while receiving props, you could use the normal and curly braces to receive the exact value. `(count)` will give you whole props whereas `({ count })` gives you the exact count value passed into props.

```
function MySubComponent({ count }) { ... }
```

Finally,

**MyComponent.js**

```
function MyComponent() {
  let [state, setState] = useState({ count: 1 });
  return <MySubComponent count={state.count} />;
}

export default MyComponent;
```

**MySubComponent.js**,

```
function MySubComponent({ count }) {
  console.log(count);
  return null;
}
```

[**Working Codesandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/manirajmurugan-cf7gf)